# How to use Copy method in base class when creating new instance

Tags: c#

I have a class B which derives from another class A. Class A implements a Copy method. How can I implement a Copy method in class B which makes use of A.Copy() ?

There are reasons (possibly not good ones) why I have not used Clone and why I would like to have this inheritance structure.

```
class A 
{
    ... properties ...
    public A Copy()
    {
        ...copy properties....
    }
}

class B : A 
{
    ... one extra property ...
    public B Copy()
    {
        // how to copy base()??
        ...copy extra propertie....
    }
}
```

Comment: Base.Copy()? see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: [My blog answers this question](http://blog.chrishowie.com/2013/01/22/object-copying-in-c/).  I'm not going to post it as an answer (I don't like to promote my own sites in an answer) but anyone else who finds it useful is free to.

Comment: @cdhowie: Nice blog. That does cloning/copying well.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thank you. dtb's answer makes nice use of protected copy constructors to reduce a lot of the boilerplate code required by my blog entry. I might have to write a follow-up post now.

Answer (score 3):

A common solution is to define a constructor that copies all properties from another instance. Derived classes then copy the properties defined in their class and call the base constructor to copy the properties of the base class.

```
class A 
{
    // properties

    protected A(A other)
    {
        // copy properties
    }

    public A Clone()
    {
        A clone = CloneCore() as A;
        if (clone == null)
            throw new NotImplementedException("Clone Not Implemented Correctly");
        return clone;
    }

    protected virtual object CloneCore()
    {
        return new A(this);
    }
}
```

```
class B : A 
{
    // one extra property

    protected B(B other) : base(other)
    {
        // copy extra property
    }

    public new B Clone()
    {
        B clone = CloneCore() as B;
        if (clone == null)
            throw new NotImplementedException("Clone Not Implemented Correctly");
        return clone;
    }

    protected override object CloneCore()
    {
        return new B(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, I deleted my original comment and upvoted once I realized my mistake. I've seen this pattern a lot, only with public constructors, and it's always bugged me.  I completely missed the fact that your constructors are protected.  +1

Comment: Yep, public copy ctors bad, protected copy ctors ok. This is the similar to what my example is doing (but mine's also using abstract classes and is showing the actual properties being copied so it looks a LOT more complicated!)

Comment: Hmmm... my solution might be a bit too simple. If you have a `B` instance in an `A` variable and call `Copy` then you get an `A` and not a `B`. I'll fix that...

Answer (score 1):

You often implement this via protected copy constructors.

Here's a sample program which demonstrates (it uses the term "Clone" instead of "Copy", but the effect is the same.

I realise you said you don't want cloning, but copying is really the same thing, at least in this context.

Anyway, perhaps this will give you some ideas. Change all occurrences of "Clone" to "Copy" if you want... ;)

Also, the use of ICloneable is frowned upon these days. Still, this shows the general approach.

Note: This is a complete compilable sample that also uses an abstract base class which has properties, and implements GetHashCode() - so it looks quite complicated. Because if you do everything right, it does get complicated...

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

/*

This code demonstrates a cloning pattern that you can use for class hierarchies.

The abstract base class specifies an abstract Clone() method which must be implemented by all derived classes.
Every class except the abstract base class must have a protected copy constructor. 

This protected copy constructor will:

(1) call the base class' copy constructor, and 
(2) set any new fields introduced in the derived class.

This code also demonstrates an implementation of Equals() and CopyFrom().

*/

namespace CloningPattern
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Derived2 test = new Derived2()
            {
                IntValue = 1,
                StringValue = "s",
                DoubleValue = 2,
                ShortValue = 3
            };

            Derived2 copy = Clone(test);
            Console.WriteLine(copy);
        }

        static Derived2 Clone(AbstractBase item)
        {
            AbstractBase abstractBase = (AbstractBase) item.Clone();
            Derived2 result = abstractBase as Derived2;
            Debug.Assert(result != null);
            return result;
        }
    }

    public abstract class AbstractBase: ICloneable
    {
        // Sample data field.

        public int IntValue { get; set; }

        // Canonical way of providing a Clone() operation
        // (except that this is abstract rather than virtual, since this class
        // is itself abstract).

        public abstract object Clone();

        // Default constructor.

        protected AbstractBase(){}

        // Copy constructor.

        protected AbstractBase(AbstractBase other)
        {
            if (other == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("other");
            }

            this.copyFrom(other);
        }

        // Copy from another instance over the top of an already existing instance.

        public virtual void CopyFrom(AbstractBase other)
        {
            if (other == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("other");
            }

            this.copyFrom(other);
        }

        // Equality check.

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (this.GetType() != obj.GetType())
            {
                return false;
            }

            AbstractBase other = (AbstractBase)obj;

            return (this.IntValue == other.IntValue);
        }

        // Get hash code.

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.IntValue.GetHashCode();
        }

        // ToString() for debug purposes.

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "IntValue = " + IntValue;
        }

        // Implement copying fields in a private non-virtual method, called from more than one place.

        private void copyFrom(AbstractBase other)  // 'other' cannot be null, so no check for nullness is made.
        {
            this.IntValue = other.IntValue;
        }
    }

    public abstract class AbstractDerived: AbstractBase
    {
        // Sample data field.

        public short ShortValue{ get; set; }

        // Default constructor.

        protected AbstractDerived(){}

        // Copy constructor.

        protected AbstractDerived(AbstractDerived other): base(other)
        {
            this.copyFrom(other);
        }

        // Copy from another instance over the top of an already existing instance.

        public override void CopyFrom(AbstractBase other)
        {
            base.CopyFrom(other);
            this.copyFrom(other as AbstractDerived);
        }

        // Comparison.

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (!base.Equals(obj))
            {
                return false;
            }

            AbstractDerived other = (AbstractDerived)obj;  // This must succeed because if the types are different, base.Equals() returns false.

            return (this.IntValue == other.IntValue);
        }

        // Get hash code.

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            // "Standard" way of combining hash codes from subfields.

            int hash = 17;

            hash = hash * 23 + base.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + this.ShortValue.GetHashCode();

            return hash;
        }

        // ToString() for debug purposes.

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return base.ToString() + ", ShortValue = " + ShortValue;
        }

        // This abstract class doesn't need to implement Clone() because no instances of it
        // can ever be created, on account of it being abstract and all that.
        // If you COULD, it would look like this (but you can't so this won't compile):

        // public override object Clone()
        // {
        //     return new AbstractDerived(this);
        // }

        // Implement copying fields in a private non-virtual method, called from more than one place.

        private void copyFrom(AbstractDerived other)  // Other could be null, so check for nullness.
        {
            if (other != null)
            {
                this.ShortValue = other.ShortValue;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Derived1: AbstractDerived
    {
        // Must declare a default constructor.

        public Derived1(){}

        // Sample data field.

        public string StringValue{ get; set; }

        // Implement Clone() by simply using this class' copy constructor.

        public override object Clone()
        {
            return new Derived1(this);
        }

        // Copy from another instance over the top of an already existing instance.

        public override void CopyFrom(AbstractBase other)
        {
            base.CopyFrom(other);
            this.copyFrom(other as Derived1);
        }

        // Equality check.

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (!base.Equals(obj))
            {
                return false;
            }

            Derived1 other = (Derived1)obj;  // This must succeed because if the types are different, base.Equals() returns false.

            return (this.StringValue == other.StringValue);
        }

        // Get hash code.

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            // "Standard" way of combining hash codes from subfields.

            int hash = 17;

            hash = hash * 23 + base.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + this.StringValue.GetHashCode();

            return hash;
        }

        // ToString() for debug purposes.

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return base.ToString() + ", StringValue = " + StringValue;
        }

        // Protected copy constructor. Used to implement Clone().
        // Also called by a derived class' copy constructor.

        protected Derived1(Derived1 other): base(other)
        {
            this.copyFrom(other);
        }

        // Implement copying fields in a private non-virtual method, called from more than one place.

        private void copyFrom(Derived1 other)  // Other could be null, so check for nullness.
        {
            if (other != null)
            {
                this.StringValue = other.StringValue;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Derived2: Derived1
    {
        // Must declare a default constructor.

        public Derived2(){}

        // Sample data field.

        public double DoubleValue{ get; set; }

        // Implement Clone() by simply using this class' copy constructor.

        public override object Clone()
        {
            return new Derived2(this);
        }

        // Copy from another instance over the top of an already existing instance.

        public override void CopyFrom(AbstractBase other)
        {
            base.CopyFrom(other);
            this.copyFrom(other as Derived2);
        }

        // Equality check.

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (!base.Equals(obj))
            {
                return false;
            }

            Derived2 other = (Derived2)obj;  // This must succeed because if the types are different, base.Equals() returns false.

            return (this.DoubleValue == other.DoubleValue);
        }

        // Get hash code.

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            // "Standard" way of combining hash codes from subfields.

            int hash = 17;

            hash = hash * 23 + base.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + this.DoubleValue.GetHashCode();

            return hash;
        }

        // ToString() for debug purposes.

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return base.ToString() + ", DoubleValue = " + DoubleValue;
        }

        // Protected copy constructor. Used to implement Clone().
        // Also called by a derived class' copy constructor.

        protected Derived2(Derived2 other): base(other)
        {
            // Canonical implementation: use ":base(other)" to copy all
            // the base fields (which recursively applies all the way to the ultimate base)
            // and then explicitly copy any of this class' fields here:

            this.copyFrom(other);
        }

        // Implement copying fields in a private non-virtual method, called from more than one place.

        private void copyFrom(Derived2 other)  // Other could be null, so check for nullness.
        {
            if (other != null)
            {
                this.DoubleValue = other.DoubleValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is that long, any sane person will give up. Does not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't.

Since `A.Copy()` returns type `A` it cannot be changed to return a `B`.

There is already a method on your object that will copy all of the fields into a new object.  It's called `object.MemberwiseClone()`.  Be careful with this though, because it will perform a **shallow copy**.  (Meaning all reference type members will point to the existing objects).

From what I've found, you typically want a **deep copy**, unfortunately this means that you will have to write a 'deep copy' method in *every class* that can be contained by `A`.

A `Clone()` method is typically understood to be a deep copy. (comments always help)  And, it returns `object`.  This will require a cast if you want a `B` back.  There's not really a good way around this since you cannot change the signature for an inherited method.

One more thing: don't use the `new` keyword when defining a function.  It breaks polymorphism and can result in hard-to-find bugs.

```
public class A : IClonable {
   public ReferenceType member1;
   public int member2;

   public object Clone() {
       var clone = this.MemberwiseClone() as A;  //shallow copy
       clone.CloneReferenceMembers();            //deep copy
       return clone;
   }
   public virtual void CloneReferenceMembers(){
      this.member1 = this.member1.Clone();
   }

}

public class B : A {
   public AnotherReferenceType member3;
   public int member4;

    public override void CloneReferenceMembers(){
       base.CloneReferenceMembers();
       this.member3 = this.member3.Clone();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [base](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) keyword, which is used to access members of the parent class.

```
class B : A 
{
    ... extra properties ...
    public B Copy()
    {
        base.Copy();
        ... copy extra properties ...
    }
}
```